# Visual Studio SQL returning duplicate values

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have a database that stores employees full names, and I am trying to use that database through SQL to print our their names. The problem is, that database contains employee names multiple times, and the query I built prints them out multiple times, when I only need it once. This is what I have:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource25" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IntranetDB %>" SelectCommand="SELECT  DISTINCT TOP (3) Permissions.id, Permissions.username, Permissions.grouping, Permissions.isContentManager, Permissions.CMRegion, Recognize.give, Recognize.receive, Recognize.fullnameGive, Recognize.fullnameReceive, 
           CASE WHEN Permissions.username = Recognize.give THEN Recognize.fullnameGive WHEN Permissions.username = Recognize.receive THEN Recognize.fullnameReceive END AS Expr1
FROM    Permissions INNER JOIN
           Recognize ON Permissions.username = Recognize.give OR Permissions.username = Recognize.receive
WHERE  (Permissions.grouping = 'design') AND (Permissions.isContentManager = 'yes')">
                   
          
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView17" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource25">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" SortExpression="id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Content Manager" visible="false" SortExpression="username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="grouping" HeaderText="grouping" Visible="False" SortExpression="grouping" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="isContentManager" HeaderText="isContentManager" Visible="False" SortExpression="isContentManager" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="Content Manager" Visible="True" SortExpression="Expr1" />
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
```

This is what is printing:

```
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Bob Smith
```

This is what I want:

```
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Joey Wool
Content Manager: Sarah Jones
```

If it helps, the three employee names I am trying to print are from different regions (CMRegions) i.e. florida, mid-atlantic, north etc. So, I tried using the DISTINCT function, but that didn't work. So then I tried thinking of a way to print it so that their CMRegions factor in, but I wasn't sure how.

Comment: The issue is in your SQL/data, not Visual Studio.  What database are you using?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post sample data for both tables so we can help you. Also, the XML wrapper around your query appears irrelevant - this seems to be a question about SQL, not VS. You'll get more help if you remove these barriers.

Comment: I'm an intern, how can I check what database im using?